# Good practice in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to JavaScript and react. I have a scenario in which I have a lot of checkboxes, about 60. I am getting data from server and then updating the state of my checkboxes. The problem is on older phone it is taking time to check or uncheck the checkbox.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
checkBox1: true,
checbox2:false //all the way upto 60.....
checkbox60:false
});
```

In checkBox component class onPress I am toggling the state

```
onPress={()=> setData(prevState=>({...prevState, [props.checkBoxName]: props.instance === 'n' ? 
'y' : 'n'}))}
```

I understand why this is taking time, is there any better way to manage this case ?

Comment: Having everything in the same state is a problem indeed. I don't like giving this answer, so I'm only commenting, but you might want to try one of the form libraries that exists for React (Formik or React Hook Form), they're optimized and you might not have this performance problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the embedded code snippet. However, you are making this in a good way and the performance issue is not expected. Anyway, try to use `useCallback` hook to handle your onPress function

Comment: @VictorJozwicki thankyou for the suggestion I will look into Formik.

Comment: @YamanKATBY Thankyou for pointing out, I will try it.

Comment: https://formik.org/docs/examples/checkboxes

Comment: In general this shouldn't have all that big of a performance impact if it is just about rendering 60 checkboxes. React can maintain much larger trees than that without real performance issues. The provided useState example is also how I would implement this without using any external libraries. In the end copying a few hundred references to a few new objects isn't substantial enough to cause a real performance hit. Are you sure this is your problem? Or are there other side-effects at play which might cause extra rerenders? (Are you setting your `key` property properly on each checkbox?)

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to create a checked state and define how many checkboxes you need.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
const numberOfCheckboxes = 60
```

Second you should create a function that sets the value for `checked`.

```
const onChangeHandler = (val) => {
  setChecked(val);
}
```

Third this is what the checkbox input should look like. You would populate it using `numberOfCheckboxes`.

```
{Array.from(Array(numberOfCheckboxes), (e, i) => {
    return (
     <input
       name={String(i)}
       checked={checked === String(i)}
       onChange={() => onChangeHandler(String(i))}
       type="checkbox"
     )
/>
  })}
```